# How did JB get away with the shooting in the first episode?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-man-in-the-high-castle

How did Joe get away with the shooting the Nazi soldier in the first episode of *The Man in the High Castle*, coming to know what we find out about him at the end of the first episode?

Do double/undercover agents get special exemption from certain laws, particularly in a totalitarian/fascist society? Where do they/would they draw the line at certain illegal behaviours in the line of duty?

I guess I'm asking for answers both in the context of the canon and parallels in the real world, perhaps a combination of the two.

P.S I've tried to make it relatively spoiler friendly, despite it being only the first episode. Let me know if the formatting works or needs changing

Comment: You don't really have to worry about spoilers inside the question body. Whoever reads the question knows what he's engaging to. It's much more important to keep your question as clear and to the point as possible. The only place you should really avoid spoilers is the question title (which, judging as someone who has no knowledge of that show, you seem to have achieved).

Comment: Thanks @NapoleonWilson, I figured I'd stay on the safe side as I couldn't find it in the help section.

Comment: It's actually [on this help center page](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (the section about spoilers). I know it doesn't really fit there, but that's unfortunately one of the very few help center pages that's customizable per site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we discover in season two:

> Joe's father is a high-ranking Reichsminister.

This is probably why Joe gets away with a lot of things.